# Programs works when compiled in clang, but not gcc in Windows

Tags: c, gcc, clang

Have this search function that works when I compile in Linux using clang, but on Windows using MinGW gcc, I do not get the right answer.  Included in the code is an array where clearly the value I'm looking for is in the array. So output should be "Found it!".  Anyone know what might the issue be with windows?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h> 


bool re_search(int value, int values[], int first, int last);

int main(void)
{
    int value = 12;
    int values[] = {2,4,5,12,23,34};
    int n = 6;
    if (re_search(value, values, 0, n-1))
    {
        printf("Found it!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Did not find it\n");
    }
    return 0; 
} 

bool re_search(int value, int values[], int first, int last)
{
    last = last-1;
    int middle = (first+last)/2;

    while (first <= last)
    {
        if (value == values[middle])
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (value > values[middle])
        {
            first = middle + 1;
            middle = (first + last) / 2;
            return re_search(value, &values[middle], first, last);
        }    
        else
        {
            last = middle - 1;
            middle = (first + last) / 2;
            return re_search(value, &values[first], first, last);
        }    


    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by did't worked?

Comment: @haccks I mean that when I run in linux after compiling with clang, "12" which is in the array, is found and program returns "Found it".  However, when I tried compiling and running same code in Windows using gcc (mingw), programs runs but output is wrong - it returns "Did not find it"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does not matter whether  GCC and windows.

```
bool re_search(int value, int values[], int first, int last){
    if (first <= last){
        int middle = (first+last)/2;
        if (value == values[middle]){
            return true;
        } else if (value > values[middle]){
            return re_search(value, values, middle + 1, last);
        } else {
            return re_search(value, values, first, middle - 1);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

```
bool re_search(int value, int values[], int first, int last){
    while (first <= last){
        int middle = (first+last)/2;
        if (value == values[middle]){
            return true;
        } else if (value > values[middle]){
            first = middle + 1;
        } else {
            last = middle - 1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Gracias @bluepixy  Seems starting the array at different points in my recursive function call was causing an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Your recursive call `return re_search(value, &values[middle], first, last);` is passing in both an array which starts at the midpoint, and a new value of `first` which counts from the whole array's start. You want to do one or the other; not both.

That is, you first call with:

```
values == {2,4,5,12,23,34}
first == 0
last == 5
```

In the first iteration, you try `middle == 2`, so `values[middle]` is 5, which is less than 12. You then recurse with

```
values == {12,23,34}
first == 3
last == 5
```

And - oh dear! - even `values[first]` is now out of range. Chances are, on Linux you got (un)lucky and hit the value you were searching for past the end of the array.

Comment: Thank you @chowlett, I will revisit the code.  So only GCC catches this issue?